# strange error for create sequence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the code and error message, and any hints are appreciated. Using My SQL Workbench/MySQL,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person                                
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEQUENCE seq_person                                #how to? MINVALUE 1 START WIT' at line 1
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: There's no such thing as `CREATE SEQUENCE` in MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar, what is the equivalent implementation/statement in MYSQL?

Comment: MySQL uses the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option on the primary key column of the table.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Could you reply as answer so that I can mark as answer to benefit other people (include Google :P)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually MySQL does not have a `SEQUENCE`. However you can use `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns just like described here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm

Comment: in 6 mins. For sure. Take a Cafe. :)